# How can I tell if an email from Apple is genuine? I keep getting asked to verify my identity

Tags: email

How can I tell if an email from Apple is genuine. Have had 2 asking me to verify my identity

Answer (score 1):

The from email address can be anything, so that means this can be anyone.

**To tell if it is really them:**

1. View the full header of the email. Open Mail, open the email, press <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to view the header, look where it came from, obviously you wanna look for apple.com, anything else is most likely fake. Here is part of an example of a legitimate Apple header:

> smtp.mailfrom=new_ndt_bounces@applemusic.com; dkim=pass (identity
>   alignment result is pass and alignment mode is relaxed)
>   header.d=applemusic.com; x-hmca=pass header.id=new@applemusic.com

2. See where the link goes. Right click on their "Verify" link, paste it in a text editor and verify if you see any apple.com domains in this link, if not it is most likely fake. If it's a shortened URL, verify it first at [Expand URL](http://www.expandurl.net) then check for Apple domains again.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the headers of the email and knowing whether you requested verification email immediately before it was sent, here's what I would do.

1. Do not click any link in the email
2. Open a new browser window and type the company address and navigate to the service that needs verification (iCloud or AppleID or developer account or music/book sales account or ...)
3. If you can't find the verification section with some 5 minutes of trying, call the company on he phone for guidance.

The time it will take for you to recover your account if you end up getting phished is far far greater than the time you will take to make sure you have a legitimate email before clicking on the link.

Resources include:

### - https://www.apple.com/support/security/

### - https://www.apple.com/legal/more-resources/phishing/

Answer (score -2):

You can verify the email address where the mail came from. It should be something like XXX@apple.com or XXX@XXX.apple.com (where xxx could be different but the domain always has to end with apple.com)

You could also check the used vocabulary, if there are any mistakes it's not genuine.

If I remember correctly, als mails from apple also include an apple logo somewhere in a corner.

If you still don't trust the email you could contact apple care to see if the email is correct. The Apple Care number for your country can be found [here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232)

If the mail you have is a phishing mail, please don't forget to report it by forwarding it to reportphishing@apple.com, according to [this link.](http://www.apple.com/legal/more-resources/phishing/)

Comment: This answer is not 100% correct.  "From" addresses can be faked in some cases-- a process called spoofing. It is very possible for a note that appears to come from a recognized email address at Apple.com to have been faked by a third-party, and contain links to a malicious website. This is why the practice of "phishing" is so dangerous.